# What shell command will clone a directory instead of making a deep copy?

Tags: command-line, bash

I wish to take an APFS clone snapshot of a large directory using a shell script. In Finder, I can just Cmd-C, move to the other folder, and Cmd-V and within a few seconds I have a duplicate that takes little extra disk space. Using the cp shell command, it takes ages and creates a copy that takes up disk space. What shell command can duplicate a folder "instantly" the same way Finder can?

Comment: `pax` will create a directory structure then hard link files within the directory structure. That's if the cloned directory is on the same filesystem. I'm not sure about the speed.

Comment: you may want to look at the 'ditto' command. i'm not sure its faster than cp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cp command now takes the option `-c` to create copy on write clones of files.

From the cp man file:

```
-c    copy files using clonefile(2)
```

For example: `cp -c my-file my-file-clone`

Comment: Did you try whether this also works combined with `-r`?

Comment: @nohillside BSD's `cp` utility only supports uppercase `-R`, not both, like GNU's coreutils' `cp` utility. To answer the question, yes, you can issue `/bin/cp -cR` or `/bin/cp -ac`.